# Why order by count(lab_results.testid) desc is not working in C# - but is fine in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to run a `SELECT` statement with an `ORDER BY COUNT()` in C#.

The `SELECT` is working just fine in SQL Server, but it's not working in my C# Windows Forms application.

This is the code used when click the button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = @" SELECT COUNT(lab_results.testid) as 'Test Count' , labtests.TestName  
                    FROM LabTests , lab_results 
                    WHERE labtests.testid = lab_results.testid
                      AND lab_results.approved_date IS NOT NULL ");

    string condition = "";
    string groupby = "GROUP BY labtests.testname";
    string orderby = "ORDER BY COUNT(lab_results.testid) DESC";

    DateTime fromDate;
    DateTime toDate;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtFromDate.Value.ToString(), out fromDate))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid From Date");
    }
    else if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtToDate.Value.ToString(), out toDate))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid to Date");
    }
    else
    {
        condition += " and cast(lab_results.approved_date as date) between '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "'";
    }

    DataTable dt = data.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql + condition + groupby + orderby));

    OrdersDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    OrdersDataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Without order by the code working but with order by no output, in SQL Server the `SELECT` is working

What is the mistake with `order by`? Please I need your help.

Comment: The combined string will look like this: `group  by labtests.testnameorder by count(lab_results.testid) desc` ...spot the missing space.

Comment: P.S. You should have got an exception instead of just "no output". The exception should have shown a syntax error in the SQL. Did you not see that? Are you somewhere in your code catching exceptions and throwing them away, or something?

Comment: Also you really should consider using sql parameters rather than just formating the dates into the string.  And you don't need the `string.Format`.

Comment: @ADyson thats the trick thank you its working now I add one space in order by and its working :)        string orderby = "  ORDER BY COUNT(lab_results.testid) DESC";

Comment: @juharr yes I used the parameters in most of my project thank you

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Moral of the story: **always always** use parameters. If you'd used parameters, this query would not need string concatenation, and therefore be at risk of a malformed query

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all , I got your comments and now I changed the old-style-join to new style and used `INNER JOIN`
and solved the issue this is the solution :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = @" SELECT COUNT(lab_results.testid) as 'Test Count' , labtests.TestName  
                    FROM lab_results 
                    inner join labtests on  lab_results.testid = labtests.testid
                    where lab_results.approved_date IS NOT NULL  ");

    string condition = "";
    string groupby = "  GROUP BY labtests.testname";
    string orderby = "  ORDER BY COUNT(lab_results.testid) DESC";

    DateTime fromDate;
    DateTime toDate;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtFromDate.Value.ToString(), out fromDate))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid From Date");
    }
    else if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtToDate.Value.ToString(), out toDate))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid to Date");
    }
    else
    {
        condition += " and cast(lab_results.approved_date as date) between '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "'";
    }

    DataTable dt = data.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql + condition + groupby + orderby));

    OrdersDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    OrdersDataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Also next week I will try the other solution and using parameters and post the other way also .